# Multiple name values for an input item? Jquery validator uses name attribute for validation

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

I have a form with input elements with the following code:

```
<label class="label">Activity Name</label>
<label class="input">
    <input type="text" name="required" name="activityname">
</label>
```

I tried using two name attributes since the jquery validation plugin using the name attrbute to validate the input.

I am not sure how to manipulate the inputs though once the form is set, since there could be multiple inputs with a "required" name since they are required fields and need to be validate as such.

I also looked and it is not possible to manpipulate $_POST variables by id.

Comment: jquery will be pick by class or id as your choice so need to edit that

Comment: What is the question? What do you wish to achieve, and what is the code you have tried, and how does it fail? Also note that the `label` markup here is pointless: no label is associated with the control in markup.

Comment: shouldnt it be class="required" instead..!

Answer (score 0):

Use array for multiple values for same name attribute. Your field name will look like "fieldName[]".

```
<input type="text" class="required" name="fieldName[]">
<input type="text" class="required" name="fieldName[]">
<input type="text" class="required" name="fieldName[]">
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the first commenter was right. Jquery will select by class or id. I simply set the class to required.

Thanks guys,